# Efficiently match all values of a vector in another vector

Tags: r, performance, optimization, search, matching

I'm looking to find an *efficient* method of matching all values of vector `x` in vector `y` rather than just the first position, as is returned by `match()`.  What I'm after essentially is the default behavior of `pmatch()` but without partial matching:

```
x <- c(3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L)
y <- c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L)
```

Expected output:

```
pmatch(x, y)  
[1]  1  5 NA  2  3 NA
```

One way is to use `ave()` however this becomes slow and very memory inefficient as the number of groups increases:

```
ave(x, x, FUN = \(v) which(y == v[1])[1:length(v)])
[1]  1  5 NA  2  3 NA
```

Can anyone recommend an efficient way to achieve this in preferably (but not mandatory) base R?

Larger dataset for benchmarking:

```
set.seed(5)
x <- sample(5e3, 1e5, replace = TRUE)
y <- sample(x, replace = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A variant in *base* using `split`.
`split` the indices of both vectors by its value. Subset the second list with the names of the first, that both have the same order. Change `NULL` to `NA` and bring the lengths of the second list to those from the first. Reorder the indices of the second list by those of the first.

```
x <- c(3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L)
y <- c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L)

a <- split(seq_along(x), x)
b <- split(seq_along(y), y)[names(a)]
b[lengths(b)==0] <- NA
b <- unlist(Map(`length<-`, b, lengths(a)), FALSE, FALSE)
`[<-`(b, unlist(a, FALSE, FALSE), b)
#[1]  1  5 NA  2  3 NA
```

I tried to exchange the part

```
b <- split(seq_along(y), y)[names(a)]
b[lengths(b)==0] <- NA
```

with

```
b <- list2env(split(seq_along(y), y))
b <- mget(names(a), b, ifnotfound = NA)
```

But it was not faster.

An *RCPP* version.
Store the indices of the second vector ín a `queue` for each unique value in an `unordered_map`. Iterate over all values of the first vector and take the indices from the `queue`.

```
Rcpp::sourceCpp(code=r"(
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <queue>

using namespace Rcpp;
// [[Rcpp::export]]
IntegerVector pm(const std::vector<int>& a, const std::vector<int>& b) {
  IntegerVector idx(no_init(a.size()));
  std::unordered_map<int, std::queue<int> > lut;
  for(int i = 0; i < b.size(); ++i) lut[b[i]].push(i);
  for(int i = 0; i < idx.size(); ++i) {
    auto search = lut.find(a[i]);
    if(search != lut.end() && search->second.size() > 0) {
      idx[i] = search->second.front() + 1;
      search->second.pop();
    } else {idx[i] = NA_INTEGER;}
  }
  return idx;
}
)")
pm(x, y)
#[1]  1  5 NA  2  3 NA
```

A for this case specialized *RCPP* version.
Create a vector of the length of the maximum value of the first vector and count how many times a value is present. Create another `queue` vector of the same length and sore there the indices of the values of the second vector until it has reached the number of the first. Iterate over all values of the first vector and take the indices from the `queue`.

```
Rcpp::sourceCpp(code=r"(
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <queue>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace Rcpp;
// [[Rcpp::export]]
IntegerVector pm2(const std::vector<int>& a, const std::vector<int>& b) {
  IntegerVector idx(no_init(a.size()));
  int max = 1 + *std::max_element(a.begin(), a.end());
  std::vector<int> n(max);
  for(int i = 0; i < a.size(); ++i) ++n[a[i]];
  std::vector<std::queue<int> > lut(max);
  for(int i = 0; i < b.size(); ++i) {
    if(b[i] < max && n[b[i]] > 0) {
      --n[b[i]];
      lut[b[i]].push(i);
    }
  }
  for(int i = 0; i < idx.size(); ++i) {
    auto & P = lut[a[i]];
    if(P.size() > 0) {
      idx[i] = P.front() + 1;
      P.pop();
    } else {idx[i] = NA_INTEGER;}
  }
  return idx;
}
)")
pm2(x,y)
#[1]  1  5 NA  2  3 NA
```

---

Benchmark

```
set.seed(5)
x <- sample(5e3, 1e5, replace = TRUE)
y <- sample(x, replace = TRUE)

library(data.table)

matchall <- function(x, y) {
  data.table(y, rowid(y))[
    data.table(x, rowid(x)), on = .(y = x, V2), which = TRUE
  ]
}

rmatch <- function(x, y) {
  xp <- cbind(seq_along(x), x)[order(x),]
  yp <- cbind(seq_along(y), y)[order(y),]
  result <- numeric(length(x))
  
  xi <- yi <- 1
  Nx <- length(x)
  Ny <- length(y)
  while (xi <= Nx) {
    if (yi > Ny) {
      result[xp[xi,1]] <- NA
      xi <- xi + 1
    } else if (xp[xi,2] == yp[yi,2]) {
      result[xp[xi,1]] = yp[yi,1]
      xi <- xi + 1
      yi <- yi + 1
    } else if (xp[xi,2] < yp[yi,2]) {
      result[xp[xi,1]] <- NA
      xi <- xi + 1
    } else if (xp[xi,2] > yp[yi,2]) {
      yi <- yi + 1
    }
  }
  result  
}

bench::mark(
ave = ave(x, x, FUN = \(v) which(y == v[1])[1:length(v)]),
rmatch = rmatch(x, y),
make.name = match(make.names(x, TRUE), make.names(y, TRUE)),
paste = do.call(match, lapply(list(x, y), \(v) paste(v, ave(v, v, FUN = seq_along)))),
make.unique = match(make.unique(as.character(x)), make.unique(as.character(y))),
split = {a <- split(seq_along(x), x)
  b <- split(seq_along(y), y)[names(a)]
  b[lengths(b)==0] <- NA
  b <- unlist(Map(`length<-`, b, lengths(a)), FALSE, FALSE)
  `[<-`(b, unlist(a, FALSE, FALSE), b)},
data.table = matchall(x, y),
RCPP = pm(x, y),
RCPP2 = pm2(x, y)
)
```

Result

```
  expression       min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc
  <bch:expr>  <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>
1 ave            1.66s    1.66s     0.603    3.73GB    68.7      1   114
2 rmatch      258.29ms 259.35ms     3.86     5.34MB    30.8      2    16
3 make.name   155.69ms 156.82ms     6.37    14.06MB     1.59     4     1
4 paste         93.8ms 102.06ms     9.74    18.13MB     7.79     5     4
5 make.unique  81.67ms   92.8ms    10.4      9.49MB     5.22     6     3
6 split        12.66ms  13.16ms    65.8      7.18MB    16.0     33     8
7 data.table    6.22ms   6.89ms   114.       5.13MB    28.0     57    14
8 RCPP          3.06ms    3.2ms   301.     393.16KB     3.98   151     2
9 RCPP2         1.64ms   1.82ms   514.     393.16KB     8.00   257     4
```

In this case the C++ version is the fastest and allocates the lowest amount of memory. In case using *base* the splitB variant is the fastest and rmatch allocates the lowest amount of memory.

Comment: Thanks @GKi.  I would have happily accepted any of the answers provided but your `split` option was the most efficient base solution.

Comment: With some changes it could be made significant faster than my first post. Maybe there are other ways to do it even faster in *base*.

Answer (score 7):

Just to point out, you can use `match + make.unique` to accomplish the same. Speedwise, it might be slower than the data.table approach:

```
match(make.unique(as.character(x)), make.unique(as.character(y)))

[1]  1  5 NA  2  3 NA
```

---

```
match(make.names(x, TRUE), make.names(y, TRUE))
[1]  1  5 NA  2  3 NA
```

Answer (score 6):

Using a `data.table` join, inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75822895/9463489) Q&A.

```
library(data.table)

matchall <- function(x, y) {
  data.table(y, rowid(y))[
    data.table(x, rowid(x)), on = .(y = x, V2), which = TRUE
  ]
}
```

Check behavior

```
x <- c(3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L)
y <- c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L)

matchall(x, y)
#> [1]  1  5 NA  2  3 NA
```

Timing on larger vectors:

```
set.seed(5)
x <- sample(5e3, 1e5, replace = TRUE)
y <- sample(x, replace = TRUE)

system.time(z1 <- matchall(x, y))
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>    0.06    0.00    0.01

system.time(z2 <- ave(x, x, FUN = \(v) which(y == v[1])[1:length(v)]))
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>    0.88    0.43    1.31

identical(z1, z2)
#> [1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 4):

If you have some extra memory to spare, you can speed up the process by sorting the values and basically doing a two-pointer walk through to match up the data. Here's what what would look like

```
rmatch <- function(x, y) {
  xp <- cbind(seq_along(x), x)[order(x),]
  yp <- cbind(seq_along(y), y)[order(y),]
  result <- numeric(length(x))
  
  xi <- yi <- 1
  Nx <- length(x)
  Ny <- length(y)
  while (xi <= Nx) {
    if (yi > Ny) {
      result[xp[xi,1]] <- NA
      xi <- xi + 1
    } else if (xp[xi,2] == yp[yi,2]) {
      result[xp[xi,1]] = yp[yi,1]
      xi <- xi + 1
      yi <- yi + 1
    } else if (xp[xi,2] < yp[yi,2]) {
      result[xp[xi,1]] <- NA
      xi <- xi + 1
    } else if (xp[xi,2] > yp[yi,2]) {
      yi <- yi + 1
    }
  }
  result  
}
```

I tested with some of the other base R options posted here

```
mbm <- microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  ave = ave(x, x, FUN = \(v) which(y == v[1])[1:length(v)]),
  rmatch = rmatch(x, y),
  pmatch = pmatch(x, y),
  times = 20
)
```

And saw that it seemed to perform well

```
Unit: milliseconds
   expr        min         lq       mean     median         uq        max neval
    ave  1227.6743  1247.6980  1283.1024  1264.1485  1324.1569  1349.3276    20
 rmatch   198.1744   201.1058   208.3158   204.5933   209.4863   247.7279    20
 pmatch 39514.4227 39595.9720 39717.5887 39628.0892 39805.2405 40105.4337    20
```

These all return the same vector of values.

Comment: Might be competitive with `data.table` with a C++ implementation?

Comment: Sure. But my goal was to just use base R, no dependencies (including system tools for compiling C++). Already the data.table approach is much faster because most of the work happens in the C++ back end.

Comment: @RitchieSacramento Thanks for the test case. I had an off-by-one error that I fixed. But I agree the `split()` method is a better alternative.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply run `match` + `paste` + `ave`

```
> do.call(match, lapply(list(x, y), \(v) paste(v, ave(v, v, FUN = seq_along))))
[1]  1  5 NA  2  3 NA
```